# Delete a file with name '--help' using rm command

Tags: linux

just want to share an interesting or rather accidentally discovered bug for Unix 'rm' command. I have accidentally created the file named '--help'. However, when I try to delete using rm command, it does not work and it shows up the help menu for rm instead. Same to mv command, I want to rename it to a valid filename, it shows the help menu of mv.

---

[Answer] To delete the file named '--help', try to use 'find' command.

Thanks for your reading and I hope it somewhat helps.

Comment: /usr/lib/klibc/bin/nuke --help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rm -- --help`, this will do the trick:

```
$ rm -fv -- --help
removed ‘--help’
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the file by quoting the filename or by preceding special characters with a back-slash.

Both of these work.

```
rm './--help' 

rm ./\--help
```

Comment: I tried, but your answer are totally WRONG. Please try before you make a suggestion. Thanks.